# When I run a Jar file, I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error

I am trying to run a jar file to run [DETools](https://www.cengage.com/cgi-brookscole/course_products_bc.pl?fid=M63&product_isbn_issn=9781133109037&chapter_number=0&resource_id=21&altname=DE%20Tools%20(no%20install)), but every time I click on the file it just gets stuck at what seems to the startup screen. [startup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvRqD.png)

I am currently using JDK 11, and I have also tried running the jar file through the command line and with a bat file, as suggested from different sources, but get the same error.
I get the following error after trying `java -jar 1133109039_293583.jar` in the command line:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDndd.png).

Comment: Do you know if the same jar works somewhere else?

Comment: Please make sure you have your dependencies and your JAR can find it.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. @dan1st I have tried running the file on a Linux computer instead of a Windows computer and still get the same error.

Comment: Again, sorry for the very late response. @Doga I'm not sure how to do that because I downloaded the jar file from a link provided by my professor (the link above in the question.